# How to speak English fluently?

Tags: speech

I have studied English grammar for a long time. And the problem is now that I do not read and speak English very well. I'm really worried about that! How can I learn to speak fluently?

Comment: Without speaking regularly with native speakers, it is practically impossible to learn to understand the language. One can learn to read by reading **a lot**, constantly; but it won't make sense until you can hear the voice in your mind. And that means hearing native speech. Movies are OK, but limited. And highly stylized, and recognizable.

Comment: John Lawler is right. There are sites like letsalive.com(http://letsalive.com) where you can talk with the people who also have the same interest.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps developing an ear by listening spoken English would be of tremendous help. I think key to speaking fluently is internalizing the "rhythm" of the dialect you would like to speak.

Of course you should imitate or in real life situations speak as much as you can as you are developing it.